# The best place to ask: Hard disk is fully allocated... What's the best way to shrink one partition and grow another in Gparted?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My question is the following.

> Hard disk is fully allocated... What's the best way to shrink one
>   partition and grow another in Gparted?

stackoverflow.com, unix.stackexchange.com, or superuser.com?

Comment: Well, the wrong place to ask is meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @SamIam - why is it the wrong place. Surely better here than on Stack Overflow (which would be the wrong place)

Comment: @SamIam Meta is the wrong place to ask the question, but it's a great place to ask which site the question should be asked on, which is what he's doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems most appropriate for Super User.

It's not specific to Unix (from the few seconds I spent reading Gparted's "about" page on their site), so posting there doesn't seem proper.  If it's usually used on Unix environments, you are using Unix, and you have reason to believe that something related to your OS is relevant to the answer, then it *might* belong on Unix, but that would be a bit of a stretch, at least from what I understand of the question.

It's not a programming question, but a question of proper usage of an existing program, so Stack Overflow would also be an impropor place to ask.

Since it is about proper usage of an existing tool, that leaves Super User as the proper place to ask.

Keep in mind that, as is, the question is not of high quality and will potentially be closed if posted.  Hopefully you just summarized it for the sake of the meta post.  If not, you should elaborate on your situation.  You need to explain what you've done so far, any research that you may have done into the issue, and add any details about your current system/configuration that may be relevant.  (I couldn't tell you what that might be, given no knowledge of the tool.)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, the real question would be more detailed for sure. Great points. Super User seems to be the best place to post it. I was thinking of Unix because Gparted runs in a Unix environment from a bootable CD, but (as you read on their site) it can be used as a tool for managing hard disks that contain Windows and Mac OSX. In that perspective, yeah, I think Super User is better. Thanks!